# How to fit function with data?

Tags: plotting, functions, fitting, physics, data

I have

```
lambdaValue = 633; 
n = 1.52; 

tN = {1.86, 1.95, 2.02, 2.11, 2.2, 2.3, 2.36, 2.48, 2.54, 2.66, 2.74, 
   2.85, 2.94, 3.04, 3.2, 3.21, 3.35, 3.46, 3.54, 3.64, 3.75, 3.86, 4,
    4.09, 4.23, 4.30, 4.45, 4.57, 4.68, 4.81, 4.9, 5.07, 5.14, 5.31, 
   5.43, 5.57, 5.68, 5.85, 5.96, 6.11, 6.25, 6.38, 6.52, 6.65, 6.78, 
   6.92, 7.10, 7.24, 7.4, 7.57, 7.7, 7.89, 8, 8.19, 8.36, 8.52, 8.68, 
   8.87, 9.02, 9.22, 9.4, 9.63, 9.79, 10, 10.18, 10.41, 10.64, 10.85, 
   11.08, 11.33, 11.56, 11.83, 12.14, 12.44, 12.75, 13.05, 13.46, 
   13.83, 14.3, 14.69, 15.41, 15.89, 17.03};

dH = Table[i*lambdaValue/(4*n), {i, 1, Length[tN]}];
```

and i would like to fit it with a function a^2*b*(x-1.86)/(1+a*b*x) so i do

```
fitFunction[a_, b_, x_] := (a^2 b (x - 1.86))/(1 + b a x)

fit = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{tN, dH}], 
  fitFunction[a, b, x], {a, b}, x]

Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{tN, dH}], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"data"}, 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, Min[tN], Max[tN]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

but i have

[image]

how to get better results?

Comment: `fit = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{tN, dH}], 
  fitFunction[a, b, x], {a, b}, x, Method -> "Newton"]`

Comment: Both answers below give (theoretically) the exact same appropriate fit given your model as (`a==c/d` and `b==d^2/c`).  But if you plot the residuals against `Tn`, you'll find that the model leaves a lot of structure that could be incorporated into a better model.  Alternatively, that still-to-be-explained structure/model deviation might be associated with some (important?) un-measured variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide initial estimates for `a` and `b`

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

lambdaValue = 633;
n = 1.52 // Rationalize;

tN = {1.86, 1.95, 2.02, 2.11, 2.2, 2.3, 2.36, 2.48, 2.54, 2.66, 2.74, 2.85, 
    2.94, 3.04, 3.2, 3.21, 3.35, 3.46, 3.54, 3.64, 3.75, 3.86, 4, 4.09, 4.23, 
    4.30, 4.45, 4.57, 4.68, 4.81, 4.9, 5.07, 5.14, 5.31, 5.43, 5.57, 5.68, 
    5.85, 5.96, 6.11, 6.25, 6.38, 6.52, 6.65, 6.78, 6.92, 7.10, 7.24, 7.4, 
    7.57, 7.7, 7.89, 8, 8.19, 8.36, 8.52, 8.68, 8.87, 9.02, 9.22, 9.4, 9.63, 
    9.79, 10, 10.18, 10.41, 10.64, 10.85, 11.08, 11.33, 11.56, 11.83, 12.14, 
    12.44, 12.75, 13.05, 13.46, 13.83, 14.3, 14.69, 15.41, 15.89, 17.03} // 
   Rationalize;

dH = Table[i*lambdaValue/(4*n), {i, 1, Length[tN]}];

fitFunction[a_, b_, x_] := (a^2 b (x - 186/100))/(1 + b a x)
```

Develop estimates for `a` and `b` to be used in the [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)

```
(est = SolveValues[{fitFunction[a, b, tN[[2]]] == dH[[2]],
      fitFunction[a, b, tN[[-1]]] == dH[[-1]]}, {a, b}][[1]]) // N

(* {11395.8, 0.0000294909} *)

(fit = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{tN, dH}], fitFunction[a, b, x], 
    Transpose[{{a, b}, est}], x]) // Normal

(* (1591.32 (-(93/50) + x))/(1 + 0.0974045 x) *)

Show[
 ListPlot[Transpose[{tN, dH}],
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5},
  PlotLegends -> {"data"}],
 Plot[fit[x], {x, Min[tN], Max[tN]},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotLegends -> {"fit"}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`NonlinearModelFit` default settings work ok with simpler model and then`a` and `b` can be derived, e.g.

```
data = Transpose[{tN, dH}];
f[x_, c_, d_] := c (x - 1.86)/(1 + d x)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[x, c, d], {c, d}, x]
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 2, 20}, Epilog -> Point[data]]
par = {c, d} /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]
sol = Solve[{a ^2 b, a b} == par, {a, b}] // Quiet
{a^2 b, a b} /. sol[[1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use a better search method:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{tN, dH}], 
  fitFunction[a, b, x], {a, b}, x, 
  Method -> {"Newton", 
    "StepControl" -> {"LineSearch", Method -> "Brent"}}, 
  MaxIterations -> 2000]

Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{tN, dH}], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"data"}], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, Min[tN], Max[tN]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]